# How to put DIV over FRAMESET?

Tags: css, html, html-frames

I want to have DIV layer drawn over my frameset. I heard that DIVs can be placed inside `<frameset>` but it does not work for me.

The following example does not work. I don't even see DIV in Firebug HTML-inspector.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Test of frameset with div</title>

<style type="text/css">
#flashContent { 
position:fixed;
left:200px;
bottom:200px;
width:400px; 
height:400px; 
background-color:red;
z-order:1000;
 }
</style>

</head>

<frameset rows="*,100px" style="z-order:10">



<frame src="content1.html">
<frame src="bottom.html">

<div id="flashContent">
    Something
</div>


</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: A frame is basically a window object. All the rules about windows apply to frames. A div belongs to a document which is held inside a window. Since the document can't leave its window, the div can't leave its window. You're asking for control at the level of the browser, but all you are permitted is control at the level of the document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot position `DIVs` on top of `framesets`. The only way to achieve is to position your `DIV` over an `iFrame`. At least for newer browsers ([no IE6](http://kelvincastelino.blogspot.com/2011/05/div-over-iframe.html)).

As per your code example you have to position your `DIV` absolutely including the `z-index` property:

```
#flashContent {

  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 200px;
  z-index: 2;

  width:400px; 
  height:400px; 
  background-color:red;
}
```